# Husband decides to divorce her for a younger female, she doesn't let him leave, they end up together

Tags: identify-this-movie

Which is that movie?

The husband tries to leave a letter to his wife, saying that it's over and they will get a divorce. However, the wife returns sooner that he thought and catches him as he was writing the letter.

He tells her that he is out, it's over, but she won't let him go, and she breaks something to his head (a vase I guess), so he faints.

Then she ties him up and tries to change his mind, by reminding him all the good moments they had together, etc., but he doesn't change his mind.

However, there is something that gets things for complicated. He had decided to run away with a younger female, to Paris. The young woman comes to the house, but he is tied up and can't talk! The wife goes downstairs and tells the woman to go wait him at the airport (but of course he will never make it there!).

In the meanwhile, he asks to go to the bathroom, where - of course - he tries to escape, but they leave in the countryside, so it's no use (nobody can hear him). She then ties him up in the toilet.

Then, burglars come into play, but they camp in the house (2 males, 1 female), they don't steal and leave. In the meanwhile, the young woman understands that she was tricked and she returns furious into the house - but the only thing that happens is that the burglars catches her too and make her stay into the bathroom, with the wife and the husband.

A very nice atmosphere, with all the three characters in the bathroom, and with both females accusing the male for "getting us here".

Then the chief-burglar comes into the bathroom and says that he wants to rape one female, but she picks the wife, the male resists and gets punched in the face. The female burglar (girlfriend of the chief) calls him and nothing happens, fortunately!

After that, the burglars magically decide to leave the house (it was not long before after the young female remembers that she has a cellphone with her, which might be a clue for the end of the movie).

Finally, the male picks the wife and the young female leaves the happy (once again) couple in a strong hug.

At the very end of the movie, the wife says "hi with her eyes" to a person the husband doesn't know in the street, but it seems that this person is the chief burglar! I mean it's like she planned the burglars to come into play, but the movie ends there.

Do you know the name of the movie?

---

Edit:

It must have been an American movie. The husband had brown/black hair and both women were blonde. The wife had light blue eyes. They didn't have a kid, but after the story ended, they got/made one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the 2009 black comedy [Serious Moonlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serious_Moonlight_(2009_film)) with Meg Ryan and Timothy Hutton.

> **When Louise, a high-powered attorney (Meg Ryan), discovers that her husband Ian (Timothy Hutton) is about to leave her for another woman Sara (Kristen Bell), she prevents him from doing so by binding him to a chair with duct tape. She tries to persuade and convince him that he still loves her, but everything she says fails to change his mind. He lies and promises that he still loves her and won't run away when she frees him. When he tries to escape, she knocks him out with a flower pot and tapes him to a toilet.** She then leaves the house to purchase groceries to make a "romantic meal." While she is out, a lawn service boy comes by to mow the lawn, and Ian successfully yells for help and gets his attention. The boy, realizing that there is no one else in the house, begins robbing their house. **When Louise returns, the burglar attacks her and brings her into the bathroom with Ian.** During their captivity, Ian realizes that he does still love his wife, and the couple makes up. The next morning, **Sara (Ian's mistress) comes to the house, furious that Ian did not show up at the airport to go to Paris with her. The burglars put Sara into the bathroom with the reconciled couple, and the three discuss their love triangle situation.**

Directed by actress Cheryl Hines and written by actress Adrienne Shelly. Here's the trailer:

Comment: So it wasn't a vase after all...Thanks Walt! So do you know anything about the end I am talking about? I mean did the wife set up that burglar-thing?

Comment: @gsamaras Yes, this is implied (sorry, I cut that bit out). Glad you found it. :)

Comment: «The burglars put Sara into the bathroom» was there 1 burglar or multiple?

Comment: @JDługosz Multiple. The first one is their leader, I think.

Comment: The guy that puts Sara in the bathroom is the leader (the one that wants to rape the wife afterwards) @Walt. Damn I must rate this movie, it made an impact on me judging by how many things I remember!